# link2sd. Most Apps were gone after restarting

Tags: link2sd

I just rooted my phone and successfully link all movable apps to my external sd's 2nd partition (ext4) using link2sd.

I did a restart and everything's fine, same on the second restart...

but the third time most apps disappear, only system apps are there...

When I try to use messaging app to text someone, it'll crash. It will say: "Unfortunately, Messaging has stopped".

What should I do except from restoring my backup or doing factory data reset?